# How to change templates on Opencart 3. Turning of the Cache doesn't work

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I started to develop on Opencart recently. Now i'm facing the one big problem. I just can't edit any twig templates. I tried to do it via ftp, tried to do it in admin panel. Tried to refresh modificators and even deleted them. Turned off the cache. And non of this worked. Please, help!:(

Answer (score 0):

You can do one ultimate hack to turn off caching that fetches cached template by going to system > library > cache > file.php
Go to public function "get" definition and add the code below in the start so it returns false for any cached files request.

```
return false;
```

It will return false for cached files and always fetch fresh template twig file.